# Removing Alert screen as display group

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I there, I struggling again with displaying and removing Alert. I made up an Alert screen by using Displaynew group. I have two of them, one with buttons (ALert1) to chose actions and one with no buttons (Alert2) to confirm action. The problem is that when I call Alert1 and I choose the action that make Alert2 appear I am not able to remove both Alert. I call Removealert functions to make disappear both but I only manage to remove Alert1. Alert2 still remain there. Please help, thanks.

Following is the code:

```
function alertScreenScore(title, message) -- Alert1. Alert2 is similar with no buttons and is called alertScreenscore

alertBox=display.newImage("cornice.png")
alertBox.x=W
alertBox.y=H/1.3

transition.from(alertBox,{time=10,xScale=0.5,yScale=0.6,transition=easing.cutExpo})

titolomessaggio=display.newText(title,0,0,"Arial",100)
titolomessaggio:setTextColor(255,255,0,255)

titolomessaggio.xScale=0.5
titolomessaggio.yScale=0.5
titolomessaggio.x=display.contentCenterX
titolomessaggio.y=display.contentCenterY-100

testomessaggio=display.newText(message,0,0,"Arial",100)
testomessaggio:setTextColor(255,255,0,255)
testomessaggio.xScale=0.5
testomessaggio.yScale=0.5
testomessaggio.x=display.contentCenterX
testomessaggio.y=display.contentCenterY+10




buttonCancel = widget.newButton
{
  id = "buttonCancel",
  defaultFile = "buttonbn.png",
  label = "NO",
  labelColor = 
 { 
 default = { 0, 0, 0, 255 },
},
 font = native.systemFont,
 fontSize = 30,
 emboss = true,
 onEvent = decidiCancel,
 isEnabled=true
}


buttonOK = widget.newButton
{
 id = "buttonOK",
 defaultFile = "buttonbn.png",
 label = "YES",
 labelColor = 
 { 
   default = { 0, 0, 0, 255 },
 },
 font = native.systemFont,
 fontSize = 30,
 emboss = true,
 onEvent = decidiOK,
 isEnabled=true
}
buttonCancel.x=250
buttonCancel.y=620

buttonOK.x=520
buttonOK.y=620



scoreDisplayGroup=display.newGroup()
scoreDisplayGroup:insert(alertBox)
scoreDisplayGroup:insert(titolomessaggio)
scoreDisplayGroup:insert(testomessaggio)
scoreDisplayGroup:insert(buttonCancel)
scoreDisplayGroup:insert(buttonOK)

end

local decidiOK = function(event)

if event.phase=="began" then
score.add(punti)
score.save() 
end
alertScreen("","Score saved!") --Alert2


timer.performWithDelay(1000,removescore,1)
timeLimit=60
timeLeft.text = "1:00"


end

local decidiCancel = function( event )

 if event.phase == "ended" then
    timer.performWithDelay(100,removeAlertScreenScore,1)
 end
 timeLimit=60
 timeLeft.text = "1:00"
end


local function removescore(event)
  scoreDisplayGroup:removeSelf()
  alertDisplayGroup:removeSelf()
end

local function removeAlertScreenScore(event)
  scoreDisplayGroup:removeSelf()

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The code itself is wrong, you have declared the buttons inside the function , but onRelease function are declared as local and more over they are below the buttons.

First of all you should know lua is top to bottom approach, so change code as like this and try

```
 local function removescore(event)
   scoreDisplayGroup:removeSelf()
   alertDisplayGroup:removeSelf()
end

local function removeAlertScreenScore(event)
   scoreDisplayGroup:removeSelf()

end


local decidiOK = function(event)

   if event.phase=="began" then
     score.add(punti)
     score.save() 
   end
  alertScreen("","Score saved!") --Alert2


 timer.performWithDelay(1000,removescore,1)
 timeLimit=60
 timeLeft.text = "1:00"


end

local decidiCancel = function( event )

  if event.phase == "ended" then
    timer.performWithDelay(100,removeAlertScreenScore,1)
  end
  timeLimit=60
  timeLeft.text = "1:00"
end


 function alertScreenScore(title, message) -- Alert1. Alert2 is similar with        no buttons and is called alertScreenscore

    alertBox=display.newImage("cornice.png")
    alertBox.x=W
    alertBox.y=H/1.3

    transition.from(alertBox,  {time=10,xScale=0.5,yScale=0.6,transition=easing.cutExpo})

   titolomessaggio=display.newText(title,0,0,"Arial",100)
   titolomessaggio:setTextColor(255,255,0,255)

   titolomessaggio.xScale=0.5
   titolomessaggio.yScale=0.5
   titolomessaggio.x=display.contentCenterX
   titolomessaggio.y=display.contentCenterY-100

   testomessaggio=display.newText(message,0,0,"Arial",100)
   testomessaggio:setTextColor(255,255,0,255)
   testomessaggio.xScale=0.5
   testomessaggio.yScale=0.5
   testomessaggio.x=display.contentCenterX
   testomessaggio.y=display.contentCenterY+10




   buttonCancel = widget.newButton
   {
   id = "buttonCancel",
   defaultFile = "buttonbn.png",
   label = "NO",
   labelColor = 
   { 
   default = { 0, 0, 0, 255 },
   },
   font = native.systemFont,
   fontSize = 30,
   emboss = true,
   onEvent = decidiCancel,
   isEnabled=true
  }


 buttonOK = widget.newButton
 {
 id = "buttonOK",
 defaultFile = "buttonbn.png",
 label = "YES",
 labelColor = 
 { 
  default = { 0, 0, 0, 255 },
 },
 font = native.systemFont,
 fontSize = 30,
 emboss = true,
 onEvent = decidiOK,
 isEnabled=true
 }
 buttonCancel.x=250
 buttonCancel.y=620

   buttonOK.x=520
   buttonOK.y=620



  scoreDisplayGroup=display.newGroup()
  scoreDisplayGroup:insert(alertBox)
  scoreDisplayGroup:insert(titolomessaggio)
  scoreDisplayGroup:insert(testomessaggio)
  scoreDisplayGroup:insert(buttonCancel)
  scoreDisplayGroup:insert(buttonOK)

 end
```

now this should work , declare all the variables above the remove score function.

Comment: Hi Kumar, thanks a lot for your help. As you understood I'm moving my first step on Lua:). By the way I followed your suggestions putting in the right order functions and declaring correctly the variables above. I have only one question: what is the difference between a function declared as "local something=function(event)" and "function something(event)"?

Comment: If you want to know about the functions , then see this link http://www.lua.org/pil/6.2.html and http://www.lua.org/pil/5.html